# paper.js passing variables to javascript

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have a simple application that will draw a line, rect and polygon.

Im using paper.js but not sure how to control the flow.

The line should be drawn only if the line(button) is clicked. Currently, by default the line is drawn on the canvas.

```
<!-- templates/index.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Annotation Tool</title>

    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">

    <!-- Javascript files -->
    <script src="/static/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- Paper files -->
    <script src="/static/node_modules/paper/dist/paper-full.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/paperscript" src="/static/js/paperscript.js" charset="utf-8" canvas="myCanvas"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
  <script>

  </script>
  <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-bordered">
          <div class="btn-toolbar">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="draw-line">Line</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="draw-rect">Rectangle</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="draw-poly">Polygon</button>
          </div>
      </div>

      <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
      <!--<div class="row">-->
         <!--<img src="/static/images/lena.png" alt="Italian Trulli">-->
      <!--</div>-->

  </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

my paperscript.js

```
tool.minDistance = 10;

var path;

function onMouseDown(event) {
    // Create a new path and give it a stroke color:
    path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = '#00000';

    // Add a segment to the path where
    // you clicked:
    path.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    // Every drag event, add a segment
    // to the path at the position of the mouse:
    path.add(event.point);
}
function internalClicked() {
  alert('clicked!');
}

globals.onMouseDown = onMouseDown
globals.onMouseDrag = onMouseDrag
globals.internalClicked = internalClicked
```

// scripts.js

```
var globals = {}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#draw-line').click(function(){
        // how can I pass this function to paper script, so that before drawing the line I can check if the draw-line is clicked.
        // or how can I override the mouseclickevents of paperjs in javascript.
    })
})
```

Comment: Have a function to draw the line in your paperscript.js and just call it in script.js.
Based on your example there is a mousedown event, so whenever you click anywhere the line will be drawn.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the interaction problem between `Paper.js` and other JavaScript code, I think the best way to go for you is to use `Paper.js` directly in your JavaScript code instead of using PaperScript.
Main difference are that you need to setup a canvas and you have to make your API calls through `paper` object.
Look at the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/) for more detailled explanation.

Doing this, you will be able to better integrate your drawing logic into your code and you won't have to rely on bad things like global variables.

The following example illustrate how your "draw line" button could be implemented.

```js
// wait for DOM to be loaded
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // init paper in your canvas
    paper.setup($('#myCanvas').get(0));
    
    // on button click
    $('#draw-line').click(function ()
    {
        // draw a line between 2 random points
        new paper.Path.Line({
            from       : paper.Point.random().multiply(paper.view.size),
            to         : paper.Point.random().multiply(paper.view.size),
            strokeColor: 'black'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Line Tool</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="draw-line">Line</button>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [offical doc](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/paperscript-interoperability/), both PaperScript and JavaScript have access to the Window scope, therefore we can use window.globals  from the JavaScript and  globals from PaperScript to pass information back and forth.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
            // Create a Paper.js Path to draw a line into it:
            var path = new Path();
            path.strokeColor = 'black';
            var start = new Point(100, 100);
            path.moveTo(start);

            // Use the global variables a and b defined in the JavaScript
            path.lineTo(start + [ globals.a, globals.b ]);

            // Define a global function inside the window scope.
            globals.lineTo = function(c,d) {
            path.lineTo(new Point(c, d));
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // To avoid race problem, the following should not be in window.onload as the PaperScript might run before.
            window.globals = { a: 50, b: -50 };

            // Update the path from the JavaScript code.
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("lineToBtn").onclick = function () {
                    let x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
                    let y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);
                    window.globals.lineTo(x, y);
                };
            };
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```